# What exactly does "The guy's multiplying faster than a Catholic rabbit." mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

Was watching Avengers: Age of Ultron. In that Nick Fury says this about Ultron,

> The guy's multiplying faster than a Catholic rabbit.

What does that mean?

Comment: Rabbits are known for reproducing copiously and quickly.

Comment: If the average female rabbit has between six and fourteen baby rabbits per litter, then a Catholic rabbit will, presumably, double that number or thereabouts, because birth control is forbidden by the church. The fact is that nowadays even devout Catholics will practice some form of birth control, so the joke's a bit dated in my opinion. P.S I have *no* idea who this Ultron guy is, I imagine he must be some kind of superhero who reduplicates himself, if the joke has any significance.

Comment: ***Pope's Breed 'Like Rabbits' Remark Spurs Jokes, Anger***: 

http://www.newsmax.com/Newsfront/francis-pope-rabbits-family/2015/01/21/id/619740/#ixzz3sdUMShia -  ***(SPOILERS) Avengers: Age of Ultron Slightly Anti-Catholic?*** http://forums.catholic.com/showthread.php?t=958656

Comment: Not in good taste to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rabbits multiply very quickly.  There is a saying that some people **"breed like rabbits"** which means **they produce too many babies very quickly.**

As for the catholic component of the joke, that's because **the Catholic Church proscribes any form of birth control,** so a catholic couple is likely to have more children than non-catholic couples.  Now, **if your rabbits happen to be Roman Catholics (and of course that's a joke) there will be a tremendous baby boom on your farm.**

> - [**"breed like rabbits"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/breed-like-rabbits), definition - reproduce prolifically.

Edit - The truth, however, is that ever since the birth control pill and other contraceptive methods became available, a large number of observant Catholics also use birth control techniques.

Comment: No longer true if we look at the statistics, Italy has one of the lowest birth rates in the world. You should add it's a cliche.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Yes, you're right. The Italian population is decreasing, from what I've heard.  I'll add that.

Comment: Ah, but imagine that these Catholic rabbits reside in Southern Republican state in the US where the legislature and/or governor has made every effort to block access to birth control.

Comment: @HotLicks "every effort to block access"?   Can't you guys buy condoms, or oral contraceptives?   Are IUD's banned? Vasectomies forbidden?

Comment: @Centaurus - You'd be amazed.  If you have the money you can buy anything, of course, but not if you're poor.

Comment: If you are taking about members of the Roman Catholic Church, I believe Catholics should start with a capital C-. Or at least that is the convention in both scholarly and popular works, to my knowledge.

Comment: @NES what about "non-catholics"?

Comment: I know *Catholic* is a proper noun. Thus I'd say non or non-Catholics, if I wanted to be orthodox about it. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/non-Catholic

Comment: @centaurus abortion is legal everywhere in the US and every state has at least one abortion clinic, but it is very strongly opposed in certain states. There are some very large states that have only a few abortion clinics. People there who want to get an abortion may have to travel hundreds of miles to do so, and it's quite likely that they can't afford to do that (which is what the state authorities are counting on). I don't have personal knowledge of any specific efforts to make contraception difficult in the US, but virtually nothing would surprise me.

Comment: @Centaurus Indeed, access to contraceptives is the heart of the recent *Hobby Lobby* Supreme Court case. Hobby Lobby did not want to subsidize health insurance that includes various types of contraceptives to which it claimed moral objections. So while contraceptives are generally *legal*, various impediments are being placed on convenient or affordable access.

Comment: @NES Catholic is not a proper noun. Most of the time it's not a noun at all, but an adjective — but when it is a noun (meaning a person of catholic faith) it's definitely not a proper noun — unless you think there's only one catholic person in the world.

Comment: @hobbs Yeah I know it is usually an adjective. But when it is used as a noun to talk about Christians who are Catholic, the standard usage is to capitalize the word. The noun or adjective *catholic*, or its negative *non-catholic* does not cut it when used with this intended meaning, any more than protestants (lower case) does, when referring to a member of one of the Protestant churches.

Comment: Obligatory reference to Monty Python's [Every Sperm is Sacred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzVHjg3AqIQ).

Comment: @NES "if I wanted to be orthodox about it" Do you mean "If I wanted to be Orthodox about it"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Rabbits are famous for having sex practically all the time, and multiplying quickly.

Catholics are rumored to view sex only as a means of reproduction, no more.

The joke is kind of strained.

Comment: Catholics are formally forbidden from using contraception, and therefore their reputation for having a lot of children. Yes ... the joke is very much kind of strained.

Comment: Catholics are not, in this day and age, taught to view sex only as a means to reproduce, that is, have a family. They are also taught, for example, that sex is an expression of love and a means of greater intimacy.

Comment: Does the word "rumored" mean anything to anyone?